# iis 7.5 - simplest way of creating a virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

What is the simplest way of creating a virtual directory? i have used iis 6.0 previously but now in iis 7.5

- i right-click Sites folder
- click add web-site
- enter physical path and alias
- click ok

it says

> binding 80 is assigned to a different site

- when i enter another short name in Host Name box it accepts but

on Test Settings it clears Authentication and gives warning on Authorization

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make
>   sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the
>   physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the
>   application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that \$ has Read access to the physical path.
>   Then test these settings again.

When i try to browse from virtual directory

> The page cannot be displayed

I have also gone to "Edit Permissions" and gave full control to all the users there.

Also when i expand my folders inside virtual directory there are no .cshtml pages being shown :S

### UPDATE

I have also tried:

- right-click Default Web Site
- Add Virtual Directory

It is created as a sub-folder under Default Web Site

Now when i browse there is a different error

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

When i try "Convert To Application" in this directory

it says

> "invalid application path"

I am giving the physical path as

C:\ge.Web

which contains

- web.config
- Views (folder)
- App_Start (folder)
- App_Data (folder)
- ... (etc)

My global Web.Config is :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="geContext" connectionString="XXX" />

</connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <pages></pages>
<profile>

</profile><siteMap>

</siteMap><webParts>
  <personalization>

  </personalization>
</webParts></system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.9.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">    
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>

   </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 0):

STEPS:

1. Right-click default web site -> **Add Virtual Directory**
2. Give Alias, Physical Path
3. Now right-click your WebSite e.g. WebSite1
4. Click **Edit Permissions**
5. Go to Security Tab and give full control to all users
6. In global Web.Config find

replace with

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

This will now show .cshtml pages inside iis

Check there is no overriding in the Web.Config under Views folder

7. Now right-click Website1 and click **Convert To Application**
8. Click Add.